# How to create Iframe using AJAX (not just add Iframe block element but create iframe from 0)?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How to create Iframe using AJAX (not just add Iframe block element but create iframe from 0)?

Comment: I wouldn't call this "AJAX" it's DOM and Javascript. AJAX is actually more to deal with back-end processing; there's no XML or asynchronous processing, so it's not AJAX.

Comment: Also, what do you mean create iframe from 0? I'm not sure how you would create an iframe efficiently without using the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
iframe.src = '....';

document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

And the `iframe` is not created using Ajax, it's created using simple Javascript.

Comment: iframe SRC should be set only once the iframe has been appended to the document. see http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36779